# Contained and login user passwords aren't working after restoring .bacpac from one Azure SQL Server to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, cloud

Contained and login user passwords from the source aren't working in the target after restoring a `.bacpac` from one Azure SQL Server onto another Azure SQL Server.

The users do exist in the target SQL Server database, but they are unable to login with the same password from the source in the target SQL Server.

How can we keep intact and make the passwords work?

Comment: The users might exists but do the logins?

Comment: @CaiusJard They logins and users both exist but the source passwords don't work in the target

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too faced this issue a year ago and after consulting Microsoft support, they confirmed that this is by design that the passwords are changed in the background for security reasons. I would suggest you to run a script or procedure to alter user passwords back to original ones after restoring the database from bacpac file.

```
ALTER USER [USERNAME] WITH PASSWORD=[PASSWORD]
```

Apart from the solution to alter user passwords, you can see the resolution strategy given by Microsoft support - 
[image]

Comment: The script wouldn't know the passwords so it looks like a dead end. Either the script needs to know the old password or set new passwords. No option to retain and keep as is. Am I understanding it correct ?

Comment: Yes, If you are storing old passwords then only it makes sense to use those passwords and write a script. No option to retain in any way.

Comment: Wow, this is great information. Thanks! I was using a BACPAC to build a Docker image and couldn't figure out why logins weren't working after the import. Is that screenshot from an email? Does this information appear anywhere in Microsoft's docs? I couldn't find it anywhere with a Google search.

Comment: Yes the screenshot is from a mail, I opened a support ticket for this because after scratching my head for a few days, I was also not able to find anything related in the docs.